# Extracting date range from RADD dataset in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a script that provides the latest event/alert from the RADD dataset. I would like to extract events from a date range, e.g. 2020-01-01 to 2021-12-31. How should I go about this?

This is the script I have:

var radd = ee.ImageCollection('projects/radar-wur/raddalert/v1')

```
var studyArea = ee.FeatureCollection(table).geometry();

var empty = ee.Image().byte();
var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: table,
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: '0000FF'}, 'Study Area');
Map.centerObject(table, 11);
//---------------------------
//Access RADD image collection
//---------------------------

var geography = 'asia' // 'sa' (south america), 'africa' (africa), 'asia' (asia & pacific)

print('RADD image collection:', radd)

//----------------------------------------
//Forest baseline 
//Primary humid tropical forest mask 2001 from Turubanova et al (2018) with annual (Africa: 2001-2018; Asia: 2001 - 2019) forest loss (Hansen et al 2013) and mangroves (Bunting et al 2018) removed
//----------------------------------------
var forest_baseline = ee.Image(radd.filterMetadata('layer','contains','forest_baseline')
                            .filterMetadata('geography','contains',geography).first());

print('Forest baseline '+ geography + ':',  forest_baseline);

Map.addLayer(forest_baseline, {palette:['black'], opacity: 0.3},'Forest baseline');

//-----------------
//Latest RADD alert
//-----------------
var latest_radd_alert =  ee.Image(radd.filterMetadata('layer','contains','alert')
                            .filterMetadata('geography','contains',geography)
                            .sort('system:time_end', false).first());

print('Latest RADD alert '+ geography+':',latest_radd_alert)

//RADD alert: 2 = unconfirmed (low confidence) alert; 3 = confirmed (high confidence) alert
Map.addLayer(latest_radd_alert.select('Alert').clip(table), {min:2,max:3,palette:['blue','coral']}, 'RADD alert')

//RADD alert date: YYDOY (Year-Year-Day-Of-Year)
Map.addLayer(latest_radd_alert.select('Date').clip(table), {min:19000,max:21000, palette: ['ffffcc','800026']}, 'RADD alert date')

Map.setOptions('Satellite');

if (geography =='sa') {Map.setCenter(-75.5,-6.5,12)}
if (geography =='africa') {Map.setCenter(16,4,12)}
// if (geography =='asia') {Map.setCenter(133.1,-3.2,12)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As describe at the comment "`RADD alert date: YYDOY (Year-Year-Day-Of-Year)`", you can change the code as

```
Map.addLayer(latest_radd_alert.select('Date').clip(table), {min:20000,max:21365, palette: ['ffffcc','800026']}, 'RADD alert date')
```